# Why does my code that adds controls in a loop fail?

Tags: c#, .net, loops, windows-phone, unhandled-exception

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
       c.Content = " Value ";
       lbox.Items.Add(c);
    }
}
```

`lbox` is an empty listbox in the UI and the above code throws an unhandled exception which is caught by code in `App.xaml.cs`. The code works fine if I remove for loop. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: You are adding the same checkbox twice.

Comment: guessing lbox can't have the same object twice (a set maybe?)

Comment: Ya..I got it people..thanks again

Comment: Is this a WPF application?

Comment: no..it is windows phone application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try putting the check box inside the loop

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        c.Content = " Value " ;
        lbox.Items.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are initializing `CheckBox` outside the loop once, and adding it twice. Move it inside the for loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        c.Content = " Value " ;
        lbox.Items.Add(c);
    }
```

Comment: It had no text, just code.  Makes for a crap answer.  It has some words now, so I'll remove the downvote

Answer (score 4):

Create a new instance of checkbox in the loop

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
        c.Content = " Value " ;
        lbox.Items.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bellow code it's OK:

in Form1.Designer.cs you must define:

```
partial class From1
{   
    private.System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lbos;
    private.System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox c;
}
```

and in Form1.cs you must write:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        this.c.Text = " Value " ;
        this.lbox.Items.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        lbox.Items.Add(new CheckBox{Content =" Value "});
    }
}
```